# how to align the table to the equal width of above fields in all resolutions and in IE-9,10,11 & chrome & firefox browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just wanna arrange it to all resolutions:

[image]

The code i have tried is:

```
position: relative;
float:right;
width:93%;
width:calc(100% - 38px);
-webkit-width:calc(100% - 38px);
-moz-width:calc(100% - 36px);
margin:10px auto 5px auto;
```

Comment: where is your markup? calc is still experimental. It does not work with ie9

Comment: share with us the full code (or even better, a working [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/))

Comment: <table id="" style="width:100%;" class="">
     <tr>
      <td class="header"><h1></h1></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <table style="width:100%;margin-top: 10px;">
        <tr height="25">
         <td width="48%" align="right"><div  style="width: 95%;"><span></span></div></td>
         <td width="52%" colspan="2">
           <input type="" name=""  style="width: 60%;" >
          
         </td>

Comment: </tr>
        <tr height="25">
         <td align="right"><div  style="width: 95%;"><span></span></div></td>
         <td colspan="2"><input type="text" style="width:60%;"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="25">
         <td></td>
         <td colspan="2"><table style="width: 100%">
           <tr>
            <td width="2%"><input type="checkbox"  style="top:2px;" /></td>
            <td><span style="padding-left: 4px;">/span></td>
           </tr>
          </table></td>

Comment: </tr>
        
        <input type="text" style="width:60%;" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="25">
         <td align="right"><div style="width: 95%;"><span></span></div></td>
         <td colspan="2"><input type="text" style="width:60%;"  />
         </td>

Comment: </tr>
        <tr height="25">
         <td align="right"><div style="width: 95%;"><span></span></div></td>
         <td colspan="2"><input type=""style="width: 60%;  ></td>
         
        </tr>
        <tr height="25">
         <td></td>
         <td colspan="2"><table style="width: 100%">
           <tr>
            <td width="2%"><input type="checkbox "style="top:2px;" /></td>
            <td><span  style="padding-left: 4px;"></span></td>
           </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
        
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>

Comment: this is the code i have tried ...i a have split it for the convient